# Hobbit monitoring - multiple graphs per test?

Tags: monitoring, graph, hobbitmon

I'm not sure how familiar people are with the hobbit monitoring system - http://hobbitmon.sourceforge.net/ - but I've got a tricky question.

I've got a custom test, which returns two NCV values. One value normally returns ~300 milliseconds, the other one returns 500 000 euro. Obviously, these two values don't graph very well together. :)

Question is, can hobbit display two graphs for this one test? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It is a programming question, programmers who maintain software systems need to create custom monitors for Hobbit, which typically involves some programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add them to the "trends" page for the host. This is easy enough you just put a TRENDS section in bb-hosts on your server.

The second easiest way is to put the HTML in to access the graph directy, that's a bit trickier.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Because hobbit is geared toward generating one graph per page you will have to break out some c skills to get what you want...You will probably have to change the variable parser, lib/hobbitrrd.c, and the html generator, lib/htmllog.c .  You might also look at rolling your own solution parsing your data and putting into http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/ .